# Definition of sub-bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

In these [notes](https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/hoskins/M15_Lecture2.pdf) (Example 2.19) it is said that a sub-bundle $E'$ of $E$ should be a bundle $E' \subset E$ such that $E/E'$ is also a vector bundle. I feel a bit confused as I can't imagine bundles $E' \subset E$ with $E/E'$ is not a vector bundle.

Comment: If you think of vector bundle as sheaves, you can have a injective morphism $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ of locally free sheaves such that the quotient is not locally free, hence not a vector bundle. For instance, look at the short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_P\rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: @Roland : thanks for your example ! Could you add it an answer please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector bundle can be seen as a locally free sheaf. But there exists injective morphisms $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$ between locally free sheaves such that the quotient is not locally free, hence not a vector bundle. For this reason, $\mathcal{F}$ is not a sub-bundle.

An example is the following : let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $P$ be any point. Then we have a short exact sequence 
$$ 0\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\longrightarrow\mathcal{O}_P\longrightarrow 0$$
The locally free sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$ is indeed a subsheaf of the locally free sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ but not a sub-bundle since the quotient is not locally free.

Comment: Thanks again ! ${}$